# Integral of a floor function

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, ceiling-and-floor-functions

Let $f(x) = \lfloor 1-x^2 \rfloor$ with $x \in [-2,2]$. Calculate:

$$F(x) = \int_{-2}^{x}f(t)dt$$

I know that:

$$f(x) = \begin{cases}
       -3 & : x \in [-2,-\sqrt{3})\\
       -2 & : x \in [-\sqrt{3},-\sqrt{2})\\
       -1 & : x \in [-\sqrt{2},-1)\\
       0 & : x\in [-1,1) \\
       1 & : x \in [1,\sqrt{2} )\\
       2 & : x \in [\sqrt{2}, \sqrt{3})\\
       3 & : x \in [\sqrt{3}, 2)\\
       4 & : x = 2
     \end{cases}$$

But I don't remember how to integrate that function.

I remember that the result is a stepwise function, not [of this kind](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/33536/integral-of-floor-function).

Comment: Graph $f(x)$ and calculate the area of each rectangle.

Comment: See this [technique](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/360323/how-to-solve-an-definite-integral-of-floor-valute-function). Do not forget to up vote the answers if you benefit from them.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You’re just adding signed areas of rectangles.

**Example:** If $x\in[-\sqrt2,-1)$, then

$$F(x)=(-3)\Big(-\sqrt3-(-2)\Big)+(-2)\Big(-\sqrt2-(-\sqrt3)\Big)+(-1)\Big(x-(-\sqrt2)\Big)\;.$$

Simplify, and do the analogous thing for the entire interval on which $F$ is defined.