# How can $\int_0^1 \lfloor ax^2+bx+c \rfloor \,\Bbb dx$ be generalized?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, definite-integrals

Let $$I = \int_0^1 \lfloor -8x^2+6x-1 \rfloor \,\Bbb dx$$ (where $\lfloor \cdot \rfloor$ represents the floor function/greatest integer function) which on solving gives the value $$I = \frac{\sqrt{17}-13}{8} = -0.876.$$

Solving this integral took me a lot of time (manually graphing the quadratic and breaking it at integral values) and I was wondering if there can be a generalized result possible for, let $a$, $b$, $c$ be integers, $$J = \int_0^1 \lfloor ax^2+bx+c \rfloor \,\Bbb dx$$ If evaluating $J$ is not conceptually possible/correct, can there be generalized solution for [1] or [2]?

[1] $\displaystyle\int \lfloor ax^2+bx+c \rfloor \,\Bbb dx$

[2] $\displaystyle\int_n^m \lfloor ax^2+bx+c \rfloor \,\Bbb dx$ ($m$ and $n$ are integers)

Comment: It seems like $\frac{d}{dx} x\lfloor{ax^2 + bx + c\rfloor} = \lfloor{ax^2 + bx + c\rfloor}$ (where the function is differentiable, of course), so perhaps $\int \lfloor{ax^2 + bx + c\rfloor}dx = x\lfloor{ax^2 + bx + c\rfloor} + C$.

Comment: No, your function is not continuous and it needs to be absolutely continuous to be the integral of its derivative. Take the example of the OP and you'll see it doesn't work.

Comment: should not be able to give a closed solution, because if the value changes drastically, it will end up with
$\sum\sqrt{k}$ form

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The function $ax^2+bx+c$ can be converted into either $x^2+r$ if $a>0$ or $-x^2+r$ if $a<0$. We therefore calculate the integrals $\int_0^x \lfloor u^2+r\rfloor du$ and $\int_0^x \lfloor -u^2+r\rfloor du$ when $x\ge 0$.

Since $r=\lfloor r\rfloor +\{r\}$, without loss of generality, we assume $0\le r<1$. For calculating $\int_0^x \lfloor u^2+r\rfloor du$, we have
$$
\int_0^x \lfloor u^2+r\rfloor du=\begin{cases}
0&,\quad 0\le x\le \sqrt{1-r}\\
x-\sqrt{1-r}&,\quad \sqrt{1-r}\le x\le \sqrt{2-r}\\
\sqrt{2-r}-\sqrt{1-r}+2(x-\sqrt{2-r})&,\quad \sqrt{2-r}\le x\le \sqrt{3-r}\\
\vdots\\
i(x-\sqrt{i-r})+\sum_{j=1}^{i-1}j(\sqrt{j+1-r}-\sqrt{j-r})&,\quad \sqrt{i-r}\le x\le \sqrt{i+1-r}\\
\vdots
\end{cases}.
$$
Therefore, for any $r\in \Bbb R$ and $x\ge 0$ we have
$$
\int_0^x \lfloor u^2+r\rfloor du{
=\int_0^x \lfloor u^2+\lfloor r\rfloor +\{r\}\rfloor du
\\=\int_0^x \lfloor u^2 +\{r\}\rfloor +\lfloor r\rfloor du
\\=\int_0^x \lfloor u^2 +\{r\}\rfloor du +\lfloor r\rfloor x
\\=\lfloor r\rfloor x+x\lfloor x^2+\{r\}\rfloor-\sum_{j=1}^{\lfloor x^2+\{r\}\rfloor} \sqrt{j-\{r\}}
\\=x\lfloor x^2+r\rfloor-\sum_{j=1}^{\lfloor x^2+\{r\}\rfloor} \sqrt{j-\{r\}}.
}
$$
Similarly, for any $r\in \Bbb R$ and $x\ge 0$ we have
$$
\int_0^x \lfloor -u^2+r\rfloor du=-x\lfloor x^2-r+1\rfloor +\sum_{j=0}^{\lfloor x^2-\{r\}\rfloor}\sqrt{j+\{r\}}.
$$
By using $\int_0^x f(u)du=\text{sgn}(x)\int_0^{|x|} f(u)du$ for even $f(u)$, we can write
$${
\int_0^x \lfloor u^2+r\rfloor du=x\lfloor x^2+r\rfloor-\text{sgn}(x)\sum_{j=1}^{\lfloor x^2+\{r\}\rfloor} \sqrt{j-\{r\}},
\\
\int_0^x \lfloor -u^2+r\rfloor du=-x\lfloor x^2-r+1\rfloor +\text{sgn}(x)\sum_{j=0}^{\lfloor x^2-\{r\}\rfloor}\sqrt{j+\{r\}}.
}
$$

Comment: Worth noting that by using Riemann-Stieltjes integral, as demonstrated [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4185229/806703), the induction step can be deduced rather painlessly.

Answer (score 6):

> I do not know if this helps, but this was too long for a comment.

Well, using the [fact](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floor_and_ceiling_functions#Continuity_and_series_expansions) that:

$$\left\lfloor x\right\rfloor=x-\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{\pi}\sum_{n\ \geq\ 1}\frac{\sin\left(2\pi nx\right)}{n}\tag1$$

So, we get:

\begin{align}
\mathcal{I}\left(\alpha,\beta,\gamma\right)&=\int\limits_0^1\left\lfloor \alpha x^2+\beta x+\gamma\right\rfloor\,\Bbb dx\\
&=\int\limits_0^1\left(\alpha x^2+\beta x+\gamma-\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{\pi}\sum_{n\ \geq\ 1}\frac{\sin\left(2\pi n\left(\alpha x^2+\beta x+\gamma\right)\right)}{n}\right)\,\Bbb dx\\
&=\frac{\alpha}{3}+\frac{\beta}{2}+\gamma-\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{\pi}\sum_{n\ \geq\ 1}\frac{1}{n}\int\limits_0^1\sin\left(2\pi n\left(\alpha x^2+\beta x+\gamma\right)\right)\,\Bbb dx\tag2
\end{align}

Comment: @User0 See [Fresnel integrals](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/FresnelIntegrals.html)

Answer (score 3):

Let $f(x)=ax^2+bx+c$ be a quadratic. The floor function can be written as

$$\lfloor x \rfloor=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \theta(x-n)-\sum_{n=0}^\infty \theta(-x-n)$$
where $\theta(x)=1$ if $x\ge0 $ and $\theta(x)=0$ otherwise.

This transforms the integral into a sum

$$\int_\alpha^\beta \lfloor f(x) \rfloor dx= \sum_{n=1}^\infty \int_\alpha^\beta\theta(f(x)-n) dx-\sum_{n=0}^\infty \int_\alpha^\beta\theta(-f(x)-n) dx$$

Each integral appearing in this sum measures the size of the solution set (in $[\alpha,\beta]$) to $f(x)\ge n$ or $f(x)\le -n$ for $n>0$. For a quadratic, $f(x)=ax^2+bx+c$ let $r_1,r_2$ be the two roots of $f(x)-n=0$. Then the solutions to $f(x)\ge n$ or $f(x)\le -n$ are either $[r_1,r_2]$ or $\mathbb{R}\setminus[r_1,r_2]$ according to the sign of $a$. The roots can of course be written in terms of the coefficients $a,b,c$ using the quadratic formula.

Let's see how this works in your example, $f(x)=-8x^2+6x-1$. In this case, the stationary point is at $(\frac{3}{8},\frac{17}{8})$ so $f(x)\ge n$ has no solutions for $n>0$. Moreover, for $n>2$, $f(x)\le -n$ has no solutions in $[\alpha,\beta]=[0,1]$. Therefore, the whole thing is a sum of just a few terms:

\begin{align*}
    -8x^2+6x-1\le 0 & \iff x\in [0,1]\setminus(\frac{1}{4},\frac{1}{2})\\
    -8x^2+6x-1\le -1 & \iff x\in [0,1]\setminus(0,\frac{3}{4})\\
    -8x^2+6x-1\le -2 & \iff x\in [0,1]\setminus(\frac{3-\sqrt{17}}{8},\frac{3+\sqrt{17}}{8})\\
\end{align*}
To get the answer, you add the negative length of each solution-set. So,
\begin{align*}
\int_\alpha^\beta \lfloor -8x^2+6x-1 \rfloor dx&=-\left(1-\left(\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{4}\right)\right)-\left(1-\left(\frac{3}{4}-0\right)\right)-\left(1-\left(\frac{3+\sqrt{17}}{8}-\frac{3-\sqrt{17}}{8}\right)\right)\\
&=-\frac{3}{4}-\frac{1}{4}-\frac{4-\sqrt{17}}{4}\\
&=\frac{-8+\sqrt{17}}{4}
\end{align*}